# How to count the number of unique strings separated by a space in each cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have strings of numbers in one column, each cell contains from 1 to n sequences separated by a space e.g.

```
1001
2034 2034 2034 
3456 3456 3456
```

is there a way to count how many unique sequences exist in each cell and place this number in the adjacent cell?

So e.g.

```
Column 1                  Column 2
1001                         1
2034 2034 2034               1
3456 3456 3456               1
3455 3455 5674               2
1234 3456 3456 4568 6754     4
```

So, I have managed to get to this point but how do I go about the range and the loop to basically print the result to each cell (to the right) of the analysed range?

```
Sub CountStuff()
    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection
    ary = Split(ActiveCell.Value, " ")
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each a In ary
        c.Add a, CStr(a)
    Next a
    On Error GoTo 0
    Debug.Print c.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: `Split()` each cell value on space, then loop over the resulting array and add the values to a Collection (with a key) or Scripting Dictionary - put the final `Count` into the next cell.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have edited my answer. Please advise

Comment: I'll answer if we can get one more re-open vote.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks man!

Comment: See here - https://docs.google.com/document/d/10YzAxKi5b0t6GSJn5_Eg9u1LIYpy6jjBVGEtSmQ_aAY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Beautiful! Let's wait for the question to be upvoted and once you post this answer here I will accept it as a solution. You Sir are a superstar! Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following from my comment above:

```vb
Sub CountStuff()
    
    Dim col As Collection, c As Range, arr, v, rng As Range
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A100") 'for example
    
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            arr = Split(c.Value, " ")
            Set col = New Collection
            For Each v In arr
                If Len(v) > 0 Then
                    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error on duplicate key
                    col.Add v, CStr(v)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                End If
            Next v
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = col.Count 'put count one cell over
        End If
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Count Unique Substrings (UDF)

**The Function**

```
Option Explicit

Function CountUniqueSubStrings( _
    ByVal SplitString As String, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = " ") _
As Long
    Dim SubStrings() As String: SubStrings = Split(SplitString, Delimiter)
    Dim ssCount As Long: ssCount = UBound(SubStrings)
    Dim usCount As Long
    If ssCount < 1 Then
        usCount = ssCount + 1
    Else
        Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Dim cString As String
        Dim n As Long
        For n = 0 To ssCount
            cString = SubStrings(n)
            If Len(cString) > 0 Then
                dict(SubStrings(n)) = Empty
            End If
        Next n
        usCount = dict.Count
    End If
    CountUniqueSubStrings = usCount
End Function
```

**Excel Example**

```
=CountUniqueSubStrings(A1)
```

**VBA Example**

```
Sub CountUniqueSubStringsTEST()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const sFirst As String = "A2"
    Const dFirst As String = "B2"
    Const Delimiter As String = " "
    
    ' Create a reference to the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ' Maybe better examples:
    'Set ws = Sheet1
    'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Column Range.
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    With ws.Range(sFirst)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If fCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        rCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set srg = .Resize(rCount)
        Debug.Print srg.Address
    End With
    
    ' Write values from the Source Column Range to the Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    If rCount = 1 Then ' one cell only
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else
        Data = srg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Replace the values in the Data Array with the 'unique counts'.
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To rCount
        Data(r, 1) = CountUniqueSubStrings(Data(r, 1), Delimiter)
    Next r
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Column Range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = ws.Range(dFirst).Resize(rCount)
    ' Write the 'unique counts' from the Data Array
    ' to the Destination Column Range.
    drg.Value = Data
    ' Clear the contents below the Destination Column Range.
    With drg.Cells(1)
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - rCount + 1) _
            .Offset(rCount).ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```